# Trying to use variables in HSL function (color functions take numbers as parameters)

Tags: css, variables, less, hsl

I'm getting this error while trying to compile a HSL function:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJVbzB?editors=010

```
@baseColor: #003459;
@randomVar: `Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 90).toString()`;
@color: ~"@{randomVar}%";
@new: hsl(hue(@baseColor), @color, @color);
```

If I'm using the `@test` variable, it works!
How is that possible and what am I wrong?

The rough thing is that this function wants percentage and I had to find a way to concat the result of the `math.random` with an "%".

Comment: Aside of the answers below you don't need any `floor` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis of the problem is spot on. The `hsl()` function does need a percentage value as input. But the problem was in the way you were creating the percentage input.

There were two problems and they are as follows:

- You were using `.toString()` which was converting the number into a String. This is not needed. You can just remove it altogether.
- Second thing to note is that you were using String concatenation to convert the random number into a percentage. This means that the value formed is a String and no longer a percentage or a number. You can avoid this by multiplying the `@randomVar` with `1%` which would automatically make it a percentage.

The below snippet (having both those corrections done) should work for you:

```
.randomColor() {
    @baseColor: #003459;
    @randomVar: `Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 90)`;
    @color: @randomVar * 1%;
    @new: hsl(hue(@baseColor), @color, @color);
    @test: 25%;
}

.generate-bg-color(@spanNumber, @i: 1) when (@i =< @spanNumber) {
    span:nth-child(@{i}) {
        .randomColor();
        background-color: @new;
  }
  .generate-bg-color(@spanNumber, (@i + 1));
}
.generate-bg-color(24);
```

When you assign a percentage value directly to a variable (like `@test: 25%`), Less compiler by default treats it as a number (or a percentage) instead of as a String and hence doing so does not cause any problems.

---

You also have a couple of other options among which one is to use the `unit()` function as mentioned in [**nils**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32227117/2606013) answer and the other is to use the built-in `percentage()` function like in the below snippet. All of them do pretty much the same thing but a multiplication by 1% is a bit more intuitive in my opinion.

```
.randomColor() {
    @baseColor: #003459;
    @randomVar: `Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 90)`;
    @color: percentage(@randomVar / 100);
    @new: hsl(hue(@baseColor), @color, @color);
    @test: 25%;
}

.generate-bg-color(@spanNumber, @i: 1) when (@i =< @spanNumber) {
    span:nth-child(@{i}) {
        .randomColor();
        background-color: @new;
  }
  .generate-bg-color(@spanNumber, (@i + 1));
}
.generate-bg-color(24);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close. There is a [function called unit in less](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit) that appends a unit to a variable's contents (if they are numeric).

Just remove the `.toString()` part, because that turns your number into a string and `unit` only takes numbers.

```
.randomColor() {
    @baseColor: #003459;
    @randomVar: `Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 90)`;
    @color: unit(@randomVar, %);
    @new: hsl(hue(@baseColor), @color, @color);
    @test: 25%;
}

.generate-bg-color(@spanNumber, @i: 1) when (@i =< @spanNumber) {
    span:nth-child(@{i}) {
        .randomColor();
        background-color: @new;
  }
  .generate-bg-color(@spanNumber, (@i + 1));
}
.generate-bg-color(24);
```

Comment: Yea, thats a nice option too :)